# HBase MapReduce

Tags: java, mapreduce, hbase

If I want to write the Reducer output into HBase, I just need to use:

```
context.write(key,put);
```

My question is about the first parameter "key"; whatever value I set to "key", it will not be showed in HBase when I use HBase Shell to check, even though I set it to "null". So what should I set to this "key" on earth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set it to null - the put value contains both the key and value from HBase perspective and as you correctly noted the context's key is not used

Answer (score 0):

You Should set the key to an instance called NullWriteable.get()